# Create a List of objects with for nicely

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I was wondering what is the nicest way to create a `List` of objects.

What I was able to come up with is either converting the used `Range` to `List`:

```
val objs: List[String] =
  for (i <- 1.to(100).toList)
    yield new String("" + i)
```

or to convert the whole result wit `toList`:

```
val objs: List[String] =
  (for (i <- 1 to 100 )
    yield new String("" + i)).toList
```

But none of them looks smooth enough for me. Is there any easier way to do this? The variable must be of type `List` because it is used elsewhere in the code I'm playing with. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use `toList` directly on the Range.

```
(1 to 100).toList
```

To convert Ints to Strings, just use `toString` and map it over the Range:

```
(1 to 100).map(_.toString).toList
```

Further, your use of `new String("" + i)` is really redundant.  The expression `"" + i` *is already* a String, so you are actually making a new String out of an existing String.  So you should just use the existing String!

If you really like the `"" + i` syntax better than `toString`, you should at least do this:

```
(1 to 100).map("" + _).toList
```

---

---

**EDIT:** Based on your comment about really wanting to get rid of the `toList` call, you could use `breakOut`.  This works by looking at the expected type (specified on the left side of the equals sign here) and directly creating that kind of collection.  The benefit is that it avoids creating an intermediate collection (from `map`) before the creation of the `List`, but it's uglier.

```
val xs: List[String] = (1 to 100).map(_.toString)(breakOut)
```

or, if you wanted the `"" + _` syntax

```
val xs: List[String] = (1 to 100).map("" + _)(breakOut)
```

or, with for/yield as you originally wanted:

```
val xs: List[String] = (for(i <- 1 to 100) yield "" + i)(breakOut)
```

Comment: Ok, thx. I explicitly wanted to use `for`, but map is also cool for me. I see now there's no way to eliminate the `toList` call. Please note I used `String` only as a dummy object type with a simple constructor that accepts an Id.